# How to make for loop in windows batch file run in name order

Tags: sql, windows, loops, batch-file

I have a windows batch file that does this:

```
for %%s in (*.sql) do call

It loops through all the sql script in a folder.

In the folder the file names are like:
s4.06.01.sql
s4.07.01.sql
s4.08.01.sql
s4.10.01.sql
s5.01.sql
```

But the for loop goes through the files randomly (not in the name order), it first run s5.01, then s4.06, then s4.08, then s4.10, then s4.07. How can I make them run in the name order?

It used to work, but now it doesn't. What may cause this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jerry's answer might very well be what is causing the problem.

You might solve it by changing

`for %%s in (*.sql) do call`

to

`for %%s in (dir"*.sql ^| sort) do call`

---

**Edit** *cudo's to LonelyPixel*

The posted solution does not work as is on a Windows 8 machine *(perhaps it did back then with Windows XP but I have no idea)*.

Following is a working solution using Windows 8 command prompt.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in ('dir /b *.sql ^| sort') do echo %%s
```

Comment: Or, `for /f "usebackq" %%s in (\`dir *.sql /b /ON\`) do call`

Comment: Patrick, your solution cuts off all files names after a space, so it's only partially useful.

Comment: Lieven, your solution fails completely. If I replace the " by a space, it finds "dir", "|" and "sort", too. So that doesn't work either.

Comment: @LonelyPixel - I have updated the answer but as I've mentioned in the edit, I have no idea if it worked back then. *(OP accepted this as a correct answer so I assume it did)*.

Comment: @PatrickCuff For filenames with spaces, add `tokens=`, like this: `for /f "usebackq tokens=" %%s in (`dir "my work dir\\*.sql" /b /ON`) do call`.

Comment: What about sort in SIZE ASC?

Comment: The  `for %%s in (dir"*.sql ^| sort)`  fails on wineconsole with "more?"

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, it will operate on the files in the order they're returned by the file system. As such, if you run it on a disk partition that's formatted with NTFS, the names will be returned in sorted order so they'll be processed in sorted order. If the disk partition is formatted with something like FAT or FAT32, the names will be retrieved (and processed) in a more or less random order.

Answer (score 2):

I too had to deal with spaces in the filenames, so I added quotes around the input variable like so:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in ('dir /b *.sql ^| sort') do echo "%%s"
```

In my case it was SQLCMD, with the scripts in a subdirectory, like so:

```
SET "machineName=localhost"
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b PostDeployScripts\*.sql ^| sort') do sqlcmd -E -S%machineName% -i"PostDeployScripts\%%f"
```